# Install addon in hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

i am using hybris version 2005

I installed addon with this command

```
ant addoninstall -Daddonnames="notificationaddon" -DaddonStorefront.yacceleratorstorefront="myStorefront"
```

How can I run adon without using this command on all devices? Where should I add what settings

Comment: I don't exactly understand your question, but have you added the new addon on your config localextensions.xml file? Add this line: <extension name='notificationaddon' />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand by devices, you mean the servers? If this is right, then you do not have to run this on servers. Instead, let the CI script take care of this. Based on the deployment strategy, your script would automatically run this command and the addons get installed on the storefront.

Every Addon does different work and requires a different way of inclusion.

1. The add on has a file `project.properties.template` that contains the properties that become active once you install the addon.
2. The addon has `build.xml` that is used to build that along with the storefront extension, whenever called back.
3. The source code including the java and XML that gets compiled along with the storefront. An AddOn can override any resource in the storefront extension.

For further information, please visit the [Addon Concept](https://help.sap.com/viewer/b490bb4e85bc42a7aa09d513d0bcb18e/2005/en-US/8adc7ca3866910148ddfe860464f0fc4.html) illustrated in SAP help portal.

Answer (score 2):

Afaik there is no need to install an addon on all "devices", the addoninstall call changes two files in the destination extension e.g. the storefront extension:

1. myStorefront/.classpath
2. myStorefront/extensioninfo.xml

These files are usually under source control, so if you commit them, every time the project is built there is an ant macro that copies the addon into the extension directory.

Additionally, the addon should be added to the localextensions.xml, usually there is an template for the local dev env and the production, both should be updated.